# Turning a button unclickable when scanning a QR code

Tags: android, qr-code, background-service

I'm developing an app with a QR scanner.

I have three activities; "Skatte" which has a button that refers to another activity called "Skat1". "Skat1" contains a QR scanner. When you scan and get a positive result, it moves on to a third acitivy called "Skat1Resultat".

My problem is that I need to close the "Skat1" activity completely (or at least just make it impossible to enter) when you have scanned a QR code, which means that I also need to make the button on "Skatte" which refers to "Skat1" unclickable.

I've read about background services, threads and intents, but I still can't figure out how to do it. I've found a code which can change text on a third activity when you scan, but I need to do it with either a button or a clickable text.

This is the code for when a QR code has been scanned and it moves from "Skat1" to "Skat1Resultat".

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
 if (requestCode == 0) {
 if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
 String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
 String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
 // Handle successful scan

  Toast toast = Toast.makeText(Skat1.this, contents, 9000);
  toast.show(); 
  startActivity(new Intent(Skat1.this, Skat1Resultat.class));
  finish();
  } 


} else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

 }
```

I though that finish(); could do the work and close the activity (I've also tried with onDestroy), but it's still possible to enter the activity when you click the button on "Skatte".

Answer (score 1):

You can use a static boolean flag with value false.
Set it to true when you get "resultCode == RESULT_OK"

If the flag is false then the button is clickable
If the flag is true then the button is not clickable.

```
if(flag)
{
button.setClickable(false);
}
else
{
button.setClickable(true);
}
```